# How can I split a 2d array with the following logic? See example input with the expected output

Tags: java, regex, multidimensional-array, methods, split

**Problem:**
We have a method that inputs a 2d array of strings, and outputs a 2d using array.split("regex")

public String[][] problemMethod(String[][] input){

```
//your solution here
```

}

---

**Example Input:**
[[".w@:~uwm-ems-87-1:."] [null] [null] [null] [null]

["w:~uwm-lec-63-1:d.w"] [null] [null] [null] [null]

["..:~fu-lu-65-3:w."] [null] [null] [null] [null]]

---

**Expected output:**

[["."]["w"]["@"]["~uwm-ems-87-1"]["."]

["w"]["~uwm-lec-63-1"]["d"]["."]["w"]

["."]["."]["~fu-lu-65-3"]["w"]["."]]

---

**What I've Tried:**

I have tried splitting with ":" regex and with "" regex, putting them into different arrays, and then merging them. There is a better solution, I just cant seem to figure it out.

**Code:**

```
public static String[][] split(String[][] input, int v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        input[i] = input[i][0].split(":");
    }
    String[][] output = new String[input.length][input[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        if (!input[i][v].substring(0, 1).contains("~")) {
            output[i] = input[i][v].split("");
        } else {
            output[i] = input[i][v].split(":");
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

**each int v parameter index represents the part of the array that is either split with "", or with ":"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I have already posted an answer using regex, but I think this one might work better (split)

```java
String input = "..:~fu-lu-65-3:w.";

String splitBlocks[] = input.split(":"); // Much easier, and expects more than just . w d @

String block1[] = splitBlocks[0].split("");
String block2 = splitBlocks[1];
String block3[] = splitBlocks[2].split("");

List<String> blockList = new ArrayList<>();

blockList.addAll(Arrays.asList(block1));
blockList.add(block2);
blockList.addAll(Arrays.asList(block3));

String[] blockArray = blockList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

After this, you still have to:

1. Loop throw the entire 2d array
2. For each array, grab the first element and supply it to the regex

Answer (score 0):

### This may or may not be the the you're looking for.
(I am a new contributor)

The following code assumes the 'prefix' and 'suffix' symbols only consist of `w` `.` `@` or `d`, but you can change it.

The code below isn't very optimal, but you asked for help with regex, so here you go:

```java
String input = "..:~fu-lu-65-3:w.";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([wd@\\.]+):(~.+):([wd\\.]+)");
Matcher m1 = pattern.matcher(input);

m1.find();

String block1[] = m1.group(1).split("");
String block2 = m1.group(2);
String block3[] = m1.group(3).split("");

List<String> blockList = new ArrayList<>();

blockList.addAll(Arrays.asList(block1));
blockList.add(block2);
blockList.addAll(Arrays.asList(block3));

String[] blockArray = blockList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

After this, you still have to:

1. Loop throw the entire 2d array
2. For each array, grab the first element and supply it to the regex

### Break down of regex

```regex
^([wd@\\.]+):(~.+):([wd\\.]+)
```

^ means beginning of the string, just an anchor

([wd@\.]+) is the group for the prefix. Here is supplied w, d, @, and . and it checks for one or more instances of any of them (+)

(~.+) searches for all strings after the prefix that begin with ~ and contain any text

([wd\.]+) suffix, similar to prefix

Comment: I realize the prefix and suffix characters may not be the only ones you are looking for, so feel free to change them as explained in break down of regex

Comment: I think one single pattern `"(~[^:]+|[^:])"` and `m1.group()` would make the job done.

Comment: Also, I now realize regex was never necessary

Comment: @Darkman your regex is way more efficient, you're right. I think you should post it as an answer